# jmeter & JMS sampler

Tags: java, jmeter, jms, weblogic

I am newbie to jMeter(using 2.11.20151206). I am trying to publish jms Messages to my weblogic's queue. I have already copied needed jars(weblogic.jar, wlclient.jar & wljmsclient.jar) to jmeter's lib directory. And, restarted the Jmeter many times. But still Jms publishers are not shown in list of samplers.

Is there any other jars needed ? or anything needes to be done.

Comment: got the answer from [here] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332955/jmeter-which-jars-are-required-for-activemq) !. In addition, jmeter also needs javax.jms.jar.

Answer (score 0):

got the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332955/jmeter-which-jars-are-required-for-activemq) !. In addition, jmeter also needs javax.jms.jar.